# Authorize Web API not working in ASP.NET Core 8

Tags: entity-framework, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-8

I am developing a new ASP.NET Core 8 Web API, but when I try to test it using Swagger, I keep getting this error:

> 404
> Undocumented
> Error: response status is 404
>
> https://localhost:7071/Identity/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fapi%2FUserRole%2Fcreate-custom-role Not Found

If I remove the `[Authorize]` attribute from the method, everything will work just fine!

Also, is it possible to use `[Authorize(Roles="Admin")]` or should I configure something  to be able to use it?

My `program.cs`:

```
using EmployeeManagement.Database;
using EmployeeManagement.Entities;
using EmployeeManagement.Shared.Configrations;
using EmployeeManagement.Shared.Services.Employee;
using EmployeeManagement.Shared.Services.UserRole;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? 
    throw new InvalidOperationException( "Connection string Not found")));

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddApiEndpoints();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddJwtBearer(IdentityConstants.BearerScheme);

builder.Services.AddAuthorizationBuilder().AddPolicy(
        "api",
        p =>
        {
            p.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
            p.AddAuthenticationSchemes(IdentityConstants.BearerScheme);
        }
    );

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("RequireAdministratorRole",
         policy => policy.RequireRole("Admin"));
});

builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Name = "Authorization",
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey
    });
    options.OperationFilter<SecurityRequirementsOperationFilter>();
});

builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(
    typeof(EmployeeMapperConfig),
    typeof(UserRoleReMapperConfig)
 );
builder.Services.AddScoped<IEmployeeService, EmployeeService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserRole, UserRoleService>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.MapGroup("api/auth").MapIdentityApi<ApplicationUser>();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

My controller:

```
    [Authorize]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class UserRoleController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IUserRole _userRoleService;

        public UserRoleController(IUserRole userRoleService)
        {
            _userRoleService = userRoleService;
        }

        [HttpPost("create-custom-role")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<UserRoleResponseDto>> CreateCustomRole(createRoleRequestDto requestDto)
        {
            try
            {
                var result = await _userRoleService.CreateCustomRole(requestDto);
                return Ok(result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(500, ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 404 is not found, and the response says "undocumented", also you defined "/api" but is not present in your url. I think you are mistaken the url. Did you hit api/UserRole/create-custom-role ?

Comment: It might also be that you are providing a POST route for the return url (somehow - that I can't figure out). But I would guess the return url is used after a successful login (or after an unsucessful login) - but either way, I don't think you want a POST route there. The fact that the problem disappears when you remove authorize suggests you are not successfully authorizing.

Comment: Try to use `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]`, not `[Authorize]`.

Comment: still not workin

Comment: Could you create a minimal sample project which can reproduce the issue for investigating?